# VBA - Dynamic column name - convert to Cells.Value

Tags: vba, excel

Within my vba macro I have the following passage of code which iterates through every row and finds a specific column, and if the value in that row = "UNGRADED", do something...

```
FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Find the final row.
For x = 1 To FinalRow 'Iterate through the rows

    gradedColumn = Cells(x, 14).Value ' Find the value for the row in column N.

    If gradedColumn = "UNGRADED" Then
    'Do something...
```

I am now trying to amend this passage to dynamically search for a column title by name, the title being 'GRADED / UNGRADED".

```
    Dim gradedColumn As Range

    FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Find the final row.
    For x = 1 To FinalRow 'Iterate through the rows

        Set gradedColumn = Range( _
                Range("A1:S1").Find("Graded / Ungraded").Offset(1), _
                Range("A1:S1").Find("Graded / Ungraded").Offset(1).End(xlDown))
'Find the column "Graded / Ungraded".

        If gradedColumn = "UNGRADED" Then
        'Do something...
```

At the moment, this passage does not work and receives a 13 type mismatch error. When setting the gradedColumn variable I assume the `.Value` function needs to be placed somewhere, but I am unsure how to proceed.

Update according to answers. I have amended my code and it seems to be working now.

```
    Set gradedColumn = Range( _
             Range("A1:S1").Find("Graded / Un").Offset(1), _
             Range("A1:S1").Find("Graded / Un").Offset(1).End(xlDown))

       x = 2

      For Each mycell In gradedColumn

       If mycell = "UNGRADED" Then
       Cells(x, 5).Resize(1, 6).Copy 
       Sheets("SicknessRecordUngraded").Select
       NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row +1   
       Cells(NextRow, 1).Select ' Find the next row.
       Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
             False, Transpose:=False
       Sheets("SicknessRecord").Select

End If

    x = x + 1
    Next mycell
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wasn't entirely clear to me what you're trying to do with your range, but I think this code will suffice for you to proceed, which will give you the address of the cell with your GRADED/UNGRADED title in the form "$C$1", which you can then pass into Range if you need/wish to do so.

```
Dim gradedColumn As Range

FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Find the final row.
For x = 1 To FinalRow 'Iterate through the rows

    titleCell = Range("A1:S1").Find("Graded / Ungraded").Address
    lastCellInGradedColum = Range("A1:S1").Find("Graded / Ungraded").End(xlDown).Address

    ' do something
Next x

'alternatively, iterate through the cells in your range like this:
Set gradedColumn = Range( _
            Range("A1:S1").Find("Graded / Ungraded").Offset(1), _
            Range("A1:S1").Find("Graded / Ungraded").Offset(1).End(xlDown))
    For Each mycell In gradedColumn
            If mycell = "UNGRADED" Then
            'Do something...
    End If
    Next mycell
```

Comment: `Offset` is a property of type `Range` so the line `Set gradedColumn = ...` is not the source of `13 type mismatch error`. The next line is.

Comment: ah, thanks user3964075, Offset "Returns a Range object that represents a range that’s offset from the specified range". You're quite right, and AMorton1989 was trying to use the value of a range of cells rather than a single cell. I've edited my answer to remove that misleading statement, but I think the code is still a suitable response to his problem. I've also added to the code to show how to iterate through the range and perform the check on each cell within it

Comment: Great, thanks for clearing that up. I have amended my code above, which gives some further insight to what I was trying to achieve. What you posted was very helpful.